# How to add a subquery query inside a 'when case' statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider:

```
select distinct
    a.id, a.number, b.number as school_number, b.id as school_id
from
    (select distinct a.id, a.number
     from faculty a
     where a.status = 'active') as t1
full outer join
    (select distinct b.id, b.number
     from staff b
     where b.status = 'active') as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

I wanted to use the above code inside multiple *when case* statements in SQL Server. How can I do this?

For that I have created a view:

```
create view v_data
as
    (select
         name_loc,
         case
             when name_loc like '%city%' or
             when name_loc like '%cities%'
                 then 'Survey'
```

Now I am stuck how to use the first code inside the *case* statement which is present in the virtual table, i.e., in the view.

I get an error trying to create the view:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.this is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<=,>=,> Or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: Both queries are invalid, and I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve. Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images.) A [mcve].

Comment: You can always try `max()` to only return one value but nested sub queries are hard to read and maintain. Can you write it all in the join or a cte and then re-use what you need?

Comment: Because in1st query lot off data is missing that's why full outer is used to obtain result from two table.i tried simple joining but cross apply happens data count is increases

Comment: In case statement I wanted to used multiple when case  and in THEN statement wanted to used 1st query output

Comment: Can you add the query for which you are receiving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE represents (= has to return) a column; you cannot return multiple columns, e.g., from the SELECT in your first query. Reduce the output of the subquery to one column.

Maybe you could achieve what you want by using the upper query several times with different conditions and joining their output with UNION.